# How can I check in xarray if a coordinate exists?

Tags: dataset, python-xarray, exists

I want something similar to this: `if fileObj.is_file() == True:` But for a dataset.
I want to check if a date exists befor I select it.

```
y_begin = 2007
y_end = 2020
begin_date = '05-01'
end_date = '09-31'
ds_so_merge = None

for y in range(y_begin, y_end +1):
    begin = str(y) + '-' + begin_date
    end = str(y) + '-' + end_date

!!!here checking if the date exists and if not trying the following date!!!

    ds_so = dataset.sel(time=slice(begin, end))
    if ds_so_merge is None:
        ds_so_merge = ds_so

    else:
        ds_so_merge = ds_so.merge(ds_so_merge)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check if a coordinate contains a specific value with `value in coord` just like you could with a numpy array or a pandas index.

Another option since you're using slices would just be to pull all elements which match the slice criteria, then select the first matched element.

Something like the following should work:

```py
first_time_matching_slice = dataset.sel(time=slice(begin, end)).isel(time=0)
```

Comment: sorry - I misunderstood your question earlier - updated

Comment: But how can I avoid that if the value doesen't  exist the program don't stops? Like when the program tries to   1)   get the value dataset.sel(time=slice(2007-02-29, 2007-02-29)).isel(time=0) that doesen't exist. Then I want the Programm to   2)    try to open the following date that mabey also doesen't exist (because the Instruments fell out) and it shall try the next date   3)   until it finds a date that exist in the data

Comment: Isel will always pick the first date. So why not use a larger window? Or slice with `ds.sentiment=slice(start, None))`?